# Subplots margins to fit title and labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, margins

I have read tons of answers on similar problems and none has helped.

I just want to increase the margins between the subplots and top, left and bottom edges in order to fit a `fig.suptitle` and common xlabel and ylabel.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

#from matplotlib import rcParams
#rcParams['axes.titlepad'] = 20 # kind of works but shifts all titles, not only suptitle

def dummy(n):
    return random.sample(range(1, 100), n)


data = dict()
for i in range(4):
    data["area{}".format(i)] = [dummy(10), dummy(10)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex='all', sharey='all', figsize=(10, 10))
fig.suptitle("Common title", fontsize=22)

ax = ax.reshape(-1)
for i, (area, data) in enumerate(data.items()):
    ax[i].set_title(area)
    ax[i].scatter(data[0], data[1])

fig.text(0.5, 0.01, 'xlabel', ha='center', fontsize=15)
fig.text(0.01, 0.5, 'ylabel', va='center', fontsize=15, rotation=90)

fig.tight_layout() # Does nothing
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85) # Does nothing
fig.show()
```

Matplotlib version 3.0.0

Python 3.6.6

[Example plot from shared code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TKMa.png)

Comment: Could you please post your matplotlib version?

Comment: Try commenting out `fig.tight_layout()`

Comment: @DanielLabbe Done :)

Comment: @Bazingaa, I have done that and it gives not difference if I include it or not.

Comment: Note that `fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)` is supposed to and does indeed [work fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7X7R.png). So potentially something is special about your case, concerning the matplotlib version in use or the environment where the code is run.

Comment: `fig.subplots(constrained_layout=True)` will fix the suptitle issue, but it doesn't do anything for the "common xlable and ylabel", though that is a feature request. (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11147)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to handle this, but I suggest using the `gridspec_kw` input to `plt.subplots` for this. The documentation for `gridspec_kw` is basically just the [gridspec.GridSpec](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html#matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec) documentation. For example:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex='all', sharey='all',
                       gridspec_kw=dict(left=0.1, right=0.9,
                                        bottom=0.1, top=0.9),
                       figsize=(10, 10))
```

The `left`, `right`, ... inputs to the `gridspec_kw` specify the extents of the entire group of subplots.

Does that give you what you're looking for?

Comment: OMG this is perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: `hspace` and `wspace` can also control the spacings between the subplots